# node: npm install:: How to get the path of the files in the following case and test the example

Tags: node.js, npm

I am reading about mathquill and found the page explainging how to install and how to use

[image]

its from:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathquill

AS per my understanding i will install mathquill using the following linux commands

```
mkdir test
cd test
npm init
npm i mathquill
touch test.js
```

inside test.js i put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/mathquill.css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/mathquill.js"></script>
 
<p>
  Solve <span id="problem">ax^2 + bx + c = 0</span>:
  <span id="answer">x=</span>
</p>
 
<script>
  var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
  MQ.StaticMath($('#problem')[0]);
  var answer = MQ.MathField($('#answer')[0], {
    handlers: {
      edit: function() {
        checkAnswer(answer.latex());
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Now in the above how to i know the `/path/to/mathquill.js` and `/path/to/mathquill.css`

Now how to run `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

you can [use CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathquill/0.10.1), which is much more convenient

or download source from GitHub and serve it yourself

```
app
|_ scripts
  |_ mathquill.js
  |_  index.js
|_ css
  |_ mathquill.css
```

Comment: then whats the use of `npm i mathquill`